# Can you have a grid using Susy that has 3 fluid and 1 static column?

Tags: sass, susy-compass, susy-sass

I'm new to "Susy" and am struggling with figuring out a few items.

I'm trying to create a row that has 3 fluid promo boxes (all gray in attached image) and 1 static box (which is a 300px x 250px big box ad - JPG file). I don't want to have the yellow box (ad) scale, but I do want the other 3 boxes to be fluid and maintain an equal margin to the right of the last gray box.

Currently as I start scaling the page the yellow box (image) drops down below the 3 fluid boxes. Is there any way for them to act as one row.

[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: Any takers on this. I'm really struggling to find a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to start with two wrappers — one of the static block, and another around all three fluid blocks. Set a static width on one, and float it to the right. Don't float the flexible one, but give it a [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) with `overflow: hidden`. If that doesn't work for you (you need overflow for some reason), try adding a right margin the same size as your static sidebar (or slightly larger). Now the flexible wrapper can act as the context for your other elements. Something like this:

```
.ad {
  @include span(last 1 of 4 static);
}

.flex-container {
  @include post(1 of 4 static);

  .item {
    @include span(1 of 3);
  }
}
```

See a [demo on Sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/gist/509ac6ba7b4b4d6b6b5d).